# A line integral involving $\log \zeta(s)$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Let $\zeta$ denote the Riemann zeta function. Using the Cauchy integral theorem, can you evaluate

$$I=\int_{\Re(s)=\frac{1}{2}} \frac{(2s-1)}{s^{2}(1-s)^2}\Bigg[\int \log((s-1) \zeta(s)) \mathrm{d}s\Bigg] \mathrm{d}s?$$

Note that $I$ converges since $\zeta(s)=O(|s|)$.

*I have provided an answer below as an attempt.*

Comment: Assuming this isn't somehow related to Riemann Hypothesis (real part 1/2, and $\zeta$ itself are a bit concerning here)... perhaps if I were to look at it? But you need to show effort, context, etc.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, see my attempted answer.

Comment: Looks fine to me on a quick glance. Unless you get other comments, feel free to accept your own answer.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, tahnks ! For what's it's worth, i've a confession to make: I derived that the given interal $I$ in my answer is equal to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log |\zeta(1/2 +it)}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2} \mathrm{d}t=\sum_{\sigma>1/2, \gamma>-\infty} \int_{1/2 + i\gamma}^{\beta+i\gamma} \frac{ds}{s(1-s)} \mathrm{d}s.$

Comment: Thus we now have $$\sum_{\beta>1/2, \gamma>-\infty} \int_{1/2 + i\gamma}^{\beta+ i\gamma} \frac{ds}{s^{2}(1-s)^2}=\sum_{\beta>1/2, \gamma>-\infty} \int_{1/2 + i\gamma}^{\beta+ i\gamma} \frac{ds}{s(1-s)}$$ which leads to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log |\zeta(1/2 + it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2} \mathrm{d}t=0$, the RH !

Comment: And then introduce the change of variable $s=1/2 + it$.

Comment: Solid addendum to your answer below. You might consider appending it.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, sorry i can't get you quite well, you mean you edited my answer and added something ?

Comment: "addendum" means something extra you added afterwards. I was saying your comments are very good, and you should add the material in them to your answer below. I did not edit your answer, but I recommend you do to add the material in your comments.

Comment: I've submitted my paper for peer review, kindly wish me the best !

Comment: What paper? I sincerely hope you don't mean you are submitting an attempted proof at the RH. Such an attempt would almost surely be ignored and never read  if submitted out of nowhere, because so many crack proofs have been submitted. If this is what you mean, please run the paper by a professor first. Otherwise, I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, pity we don't have number theory specialists in our country (maybe i can email you the paper and you can forward to your professors ?)  But by your very own admission, the argument is valid...isn't it ?

Comment: I've heard that there are a *few* journals around who judge a paper based on its *content*, not the mere fact that certain problems have a notorious history of attracting ''cranky'' attempts.

Comment: There are a few journals that would look at such a paper if it's well written. As I said before, your thoughts look fine on a quick glance, but I can't verify their validity without very careful checking, which I lack time to do. If you intend to submit your argument as a proof you will have to make it super precise and clear to show it's valid. I wish you luck.

Comment: Maybe this is standard, but what is $\int \log((s-1)\zeta(s))ds$? Even assuming you are working in a region where $\log$ can be unambiguously defined,antiderivatives are only defined up to a constant, but you are using it as the input to another integral.  Does the constant cancel out? Or is there a convention about which choice to make?

Answer (score 2):

One trivial mistake that blows your argument away is that RZ is infinity at 1 so its log is not defined in your S; you need S to exclude the real line, so you have to work for t>T>0 as otherwise, you cannot apply the residue theorem since you would have a logarithmic singularity at 1

(edited later after tons of corrections by the original poster to address various objections for careless flaws that appeared in the original computation):

The main flaw of the computation lies in the misunderstanding of the complex-log, namely that while the complex-log behaves on branch points as noted in the paper by Bui et al referred in the comments from which the original poster copy pasted his argument - so it jumps by 2*Pi*i when crossing such-, its primitive doesn't as shown by the simple example of log(z) vs z*log(z)-z on the complex plane minus the negative axis.

Comment: As you said ''trivial'' we can just ''trivially'' define $S$ so that it excludes $t=0$, in the same vein we excluded the segments $1/2 + i\gamma$ to $\beta + i\gamma$. I've edited the answer to include that.

Comment: also your residue theorem application is just wrong as stated as you do not define what the path infinity - i*infinity means anyway

Comment: basically you use a sleight of hand to make an integral zero (since the supposed path at infinity is technically empty), hence the sum of the terms is zero, hence no terms

Comment: It seems you're not familiar with the concept of an indefinite shift of a contour. I suggest you familiarise yourself with that first, and also read the proofs of Theorems 1.2-1.3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0856

Comment: there the path is clear as they use a positive T as the imaginary part of the indefinite shift - your residue theorem application is wrong (the path used in the Bui et all paper is quite clear in both applications

Comment: as noted your function is not defined in S as it was originally (and correctly defined btw, just that you have to be more subtle with your integral), while if you exclude t=0, you disconnect the plane and you cannot apply the residue theorem the way you want either, as the path at infinity crosses the excluded line

Comment: again, your proof is just sleight of hand - you move an integral to where it is zero by default, hence the sum of terms is zero, hence no terms - the mistake is very clear, you either use the original correct S where you can do that if good things happens (but they don't in your case as noted), of you use non-connected S, so your path moving crosses the excluded line and that's obviously incorrect

Comment: I saw a version of this argument on mathoverflow a while ago though it had a different set of mistakes there so it seems to be a popular one - pages 8 and 9 in the paper by Bui et others are very educative in how to use the residue theorem in this setting and how seemingly innocuous changes like yours mess up things

Comment: In theorem 1.1 the function they use is different precisely to get rid of the singularity at 1. Your argument is wrong and if you cannot accept it, good luck in convincing others because it is a waste of time to argue when you have obvious mistakes (in the original S, log has a singularity at 1, in the modified S where you exclude the real line, you just cannot apply the residue theorem); until you correct them formally, your argument is just wrong

Comment: as i said before, the points that you're raising are quite trivial. Indeed, to make the integrand defined at $s=1$ for $T\in (-\infty, \infty)$, one can simply consider $\log((s-1)\zeta(s))$, as did Bui et al in Theorem 1.1 proof. See the answer in its present form.

Comment: "where the summation is over all zeros of ζ in the region indicated and C is the positively oriented circle centered at s=1 with radius 1/4. By the calculus of residues and the fact that lims→1(s−1)ζ(s)=1, the last integral on the right-hand side of equals zero." Oops, the copy and paste from Bui fails here as your denominator has degree 2 at 1, while the numerator has a simple zero, so you have a pole there and a non-zero residue; looking forward to the new edit :)

Comment: haha, of course that was no more than a typo, why would i seek another approach yet i had fixed the obstruction preventing the case $T<0$ ?

Comment: Note: This time i will only reply if you show familiarity with the concept of an indefinite shift of a contour. Nolonger tolerating any more of your nonsensical tantrums like ''hence the sum of terms is zero, hence no terms''.

Comment: "It follows that logζ(s) is a single-valued analytic function inside S. Moreover, along each branch cut from 1/2+iγ to β+iγ, the values of logζ(s) on the upper and lower cuts differ by 2πi."OOps, that's true for log but not its primitive as the simple example log(z) vs zlog(z)-z on the plane cut on the negative axis shows - as noted the copy paste from Bui et al doesn't quite work that easy and my original objection still stands, but the main flaw of your argument lies in the misunderstanding of the complex logarithm which is a tricky object

Comment: Lol, you kidding me ? ''Misunderstanding $\log z$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$ ? You really have a nack of jokes ! But i've had enough of your nonsense. Post closed.